# How to read csv file from the registered container instance in Azure ML

Tags: python-3.x, azure, csv, azure-machine-learning-service, datastore

I have a container instance registered in the Datastore section inside Azure ML as `my_container`. Inside this container I have a foler `data` and this folder contains `my_data.csv` file. I want to read that using SDK v2.

I tried to use this code:

```py
target_datastore = Datastore.get(workspace=workspace, datastore_name=r'my_container')
tbl = mltable.from_delimited_files(paths=(target_datastore, 'data/my_data.csv'))
```

But it didn't work. In fact, Microsoft now using mltable which have the same functionality as `Dataset.Tabular` in SDK v1. But seems like it's not the case.

I was also trying to solve this with this piece of code:

```py
target_datastore = Datastore.get(workspace=workspace, datastore_name=r'my_container')
ds = ml_client.data._get_latest_version(name='my_data.csv')
```

But this one also didn't work because `mlclient.data` doesn't utilize datastore in any way.

Do you have any experience in reading files from the AML using SDK v2?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the scenario, I have uploaded a csv file in container.

[image]
[image]

To read the csv file you can use the **Dataset class from azureml.core**.

Below is a sample code snippet you can use to read the file:

```py
from  azureml.core  import  Datastore,Dataset,Workspace

workspace = Workspace.from_config()
datastore = Datastore.get(workspace=workspace, datastore_name='workspaceblobstore')
path = datastore.path('data/my_data.csv')
dataset = Dataset.Tabular.from_delimited_files(path)
df = dataset.to_pandas_dataframe()
df
```

Using the above method you can successfully read the csv file.
[image]

To do the task with  **SDK v2**,
you can use below code snippet:

```py
import mltable

path = {
    'file': 'azureml://subscriptions/<subid>/resourcegroups/<rgname>/workspaces/<wsname>/datastores/<name>/paths/<folder>/<file>.csv'
}

tbl = mltable.from_delimited_files(paths=[path])
df = tbl.to_pandas_dataframe()
df.head()
```

With the above code you can read csv file from container using `mltable`.
[image]
For more details, please refer to this [documentation](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/machine-learning/how-to-access-data-interactive.md).

Comment: This won't work for the SDK v2. Because v2 is based on `ml_client` and `mltable`. What you're sharing is referred to the v1. And even if I use path from the target datastore into `mltable.from_delimited_files(pathes=path)` this won't run due to the error: `TypeError: 'DataReference' object is not iterable`

Comment: I have updated the solution with approach using `mltable` .

Comment: This wasn't that obvious. Thank you this worked